# Pointer position does not start from 0

Tags: python, methods, tell

i want to ask about tell() method. So, have code like this

```
op = open('data.txt', 'r')
pos = op.tell()
data = op.readline()
key = []
while data:
   pos = op.tell()
   data = op.readline()
   key.append(pos)
```

and the result

```
key[:3]
[[87], [152], [240]]
```

i want my key value start from 0 since it's the first pointer position for the beginning of the sentence. but it starts from the starting pointer value for 2nd sentence. sorry, i'm new to python.

the data looks like this. it's containing few rows

```
  Sanjeev Saxena#Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.
  Hans Ulrich Simon#Pattern Matching in Trees and Nets.
  Nathan Goodman#Oded Shmueli#NP-complete Problems Simplified on Tree Schemas.
```

Comment: You never added the first pointer to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I realized our mistake... The `while data` condition requires you to have read a chunk of text, I think the correct way will be to use a `while True` loop and break on completion.

```
# list to store results.
keys = []
# I used a with context manager to ensure file.close()
with open('data.txt') as f: 
    while True: 
        # read the current pointer and store it into the keys list
        pos = f.tell()
        keys.append(pos)
        # now I check if there is some data left, if not then break
        data = f.readline() 
        if not data: 
            break
```

this way stores the final (trailing) `pos` as well if you only want the start of a row, use this

```
# list to store results.
keys = []
# I used a with context manager to ensure file.close()
with open('data.txt') as f: 
    while True: 
        # read the current pointer and store it into the keys list
        pos = f.tell()
        # now I check if there is some data left, if not then break
        data = f.readline() 
        if not data: 
            break
        # if we didn't break then we store the pos
        keys.append(pos)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the first pointer to the `key` list (you have 2x `pos = op.tell()` before you do the first `key.append(pos)`).

You should just remove the 2nd and 3rd lines:

```
op = open('data.txt', 'r')
key = []
while data:
    pos = op.tell()
    data = op.readline()
    key.append(pos)
```

Comment: I would change your code a bit and move `key.append(pos)` to the line right after finding it.

Comment: @YHoffman Doesn't really make a difference, and this way it's more clear that only the 2 unnecessary lines were actually wrong in the original code.

Comment: I agree and that is why I only commented (I upvoted your answer as I indeed think that you answered the question correctly), my only thought was that being that the OP wants to store the pointers captured by `op.tell()` I thought that it will make more sense to append them after capturing them instead of after (theoretically) the pointer has been moved (by `readline`, even though the `pos` variable has the previous captured one).

Comment: @YHoffman it returns null value. i got empty bracket. the reason i put 2 data = op.readline() since while loop will call it

Comment: @AiChan It's impossible to say what's the problem if you don't provive us with more information. Edit your question to have a part of your file or something.

Comment: @ruohola i have provided what the data looks like